# Couchdb view, finds with condition

Tags: view, couchdb

I'm new to Couchdb, i don't know their design.
I know we have to use emit() to make keys for searching.
How to make a request on view with these conditions (Like SQL)?

```
Where A = 'b' && Date >= 2010 && Date <= 2020
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to emit a multi-variate key, something like

```
# map
function(doc) {
    if (doc.A && doc.Date) {
        emit([doc.A, doc.Date], 1)
    }
} 

# reduce
_count
```

You can then query it like

```
curl 'https://host.com/DB/_design/DDOC/_view/VIEW?reduce=false&include_docs=true&inclusive_end=true&startkey=\["a",2010\]&endkey=\["a",2020\]'
```

You can try it yourself on a database I made, which is open for reading.

```
curl 'https://skruger.cloudant.com/stackex/_design/examples/_view/by-a-date?reduce=false&include_docs=true&inclusive_end=true&startkey=\["a",2010\]&endkey=\["a",2020\]'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using CouchDB 2.X, you can use Mango as an alternative. I find it easier to use and understand.

```
{
    "A":"b",
    "$and":[
        {
            "Date": {
                "$gte":2010
            }
        },
        {
            "Date":{
                "$lte":2020
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

You probably want to build an index for this query to be has fast as the other alternative response.